# Selection of weighting matrix in GMM estimation

Tags: generalized-moments

As stated in the title. Are there any assumptions or restrictions behind in selection of weighting matrix in doing the estimation? Does it exist a form which is suitable in most cases?

Comment: Perhaps it would be better if you specified some alternative weighting matrices which you are considering to give people something concrete to work with.

Comment: Given the existence of an upvoted answer, I don't think this is too unclear to be answerable.

Answer (score 3):

in general you do not need much assumptions in order to define a proper weighting matrix. The weighting matrix $W$ must be positive (semi)definite as a minimum condition. However, the power of GMM comes from its efficiency. But first things first. If you choose some weighting matrix $W$ such that
$${\hat  {W}}_{T}{\xrightarrow  {p}}W\text{ } (1),$$ where W is positive semi-definite and,
$${\displaystyle \,W\operatorname {E} [\,g(Y_{t},\theta )\,]=0}\text{ } (2)$$  iff $\theta=\theta_0$, then the GMME (GMM estimator that is the solution to $\operatorname {E}[\,g(Y_{t},\theta _{0})\,]=0$) is consistent (among other asusmptions not related to $W$).

But the important thing is the efficiency. It can be shown, that the GMME is asymptotically normal and efficient if $W\propto \ \Omega ^{{-1}}$, where $ \Omega =\operatorname {E}[g(Y_{t} ,\theta _{0})g(Y_{t},\theta _{0})^{\mathsf {T}}]$. Hence, you can choose any $W$ that fulfills (1) and (2) if you are interested in consistency, but for asymptotic efficiency you need to use $W\propto \ \Omega ^{{-1}}$.